# Is there a GUI Runner for JBehave stories that can be ran standalone

Tags: bdd, acceptance-testing, jbehave, user-acceptance-testing

I would like a non-technical person to fire off a utility and run through the stories without him having to know what an IDE is. Something like what nUnit offers. How can that be done with jBehave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be using the web runner. This would work perfectly for my use case.

http://jbehave.org/reference/web/stable/using-web-runner.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch/shell script (windows/*nix) and run the tests using Maven command. You'll maybe have to declare a profile running only acceptance tests:

```
mvn -P jBehaveTests clean test
```

Comment: Could there be a solution using some GUI tool? Just like how nUnit displays the list of tests and you can pick whichever you want and run it.